# How to have multiple databases in DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have multiple similar databases and my ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC application with an EF DBContext using a different connection string for each database. I want to gather the information of TABLE1 from each database together through DBContext in only one query. How can I achieve this?

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    private string _dbconnectionstring;

    public DBContext(string cnn)
        : base()
    {
        _dbconnectionstring = cnn;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TABLE1> Table1 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Table1Configuration());
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dbconnectionstring);
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik, one instance of DbContext can only talks to one database at a time, so you'll probably have to make your own implementation that will match your needs.

Comment: Maybe try to make a proxy class that register all of your DbContext then create a method, for each of your requests, that would make the same request on each DbContext then send back the results concatened?
Take a look at repository pattern, it could make it easier to implement from that point.

Comment: DbContext depends on a single connection string, so if you want to use multiple connection strings you'll probably have to use multiple contexts and a service that will direct the calls and merge the results. You might be able to apply the same table configurations in different DbContexts, but as far as querying, afaik, each db has its own context.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your answers. I had to update my services to do a loop for every DB and cumulate the results for every query, something like this:

```
            if (_userService.GetDBName() == "ALL")
        {
            // If Factory selected is ALL, grab all user factories DBName in a list
            var factories = _adm.GetUserFactoriesForCombo(_userService.GetUserId()).Where(f => f.FactoryId > 0);

            // Get all PruchaseOrders from all factories
            List<PurchaseOrders> pos = new List<PurchaseOrders>();
            foreach (var f in factories)
            {
                using (var uow = new OperationsUOW(new OperationsContext(_userService.GetDBContext(f.FactoryDB)), _userService))
                {
                    var npos = uow.PurchaseOrders.GetAll();
                    pos.AddRange(npos);
                }
            }

            return pos;
        }
```